# Espresso intended negative check

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I'm learning some testing with `Espresso` and I've understood how to check if an intent has been launched.

What I can't understand is how could I check if the intent was *not* launched.

I tried with the `not` on the `hasComponent` matcher, but the assertion `intended` failed anyway.

Here's what I tried:

`intended(not(hasComponent(myKotlinClass::class.java.name)))`

I managed to catch the intent not launched by using a `try/catch` with `AssertionError` but this seems so dirty.

How can I do it in a clean way?